# In TortoiseGit (or Git command), how do I know I tagged a release?

Tags: git, github

I use TortoiseGit and I know that I can tag a release using the context menu by simply clicking Create Tag.  I enter the tag name and then push changes to repository.

The thing is though that the push is done manually after the tag has been created.  Creating the tag only creates it in my local repository.  I have to manually push the tag afterwards to get the tag on GitHub.

My workflow is as follows:

- Clone from GitHub.
- Make changes locally.
- Commit and push changes.

If I then want to release:

- Create a tag.
- Push to GitHub and check the 'Include tags' checkbox (without that checked, it won't push the tag to GitHub).

The problem is that I have to push the tag to GitHub manually after creating it.  I might forget to do this or I might make the tag twice by mistake because there doesn't seem to be a visible way of confirming that the tag has been created.  I mean, I click Create Tag, I enter a name, and then it seems to be there but invisible so I cannot see it's there.  Until I push to GitHub then the tag appears.

Is there a way to see any pending tags before they are pushed?  It would be fine if TortoiseGit automatically pushed tags to GitHub as I make them but it doesn't.  It only tags locally and I have to push manually.  But when I push manually, I cannot physically see what tags I'm pushing until its too late.  It feels a bit weird to have to check the 'Include tags' box every time I push a tag.  Why would you create tags locally if you did not want them pushed to GitHub?  I thought the whole point of making a tag was to name an imminent release?

Comment: For the very last part, no, tags aren't only meant for the purpose of naming releases. Tags are just labels, and different workflows have different uses for them.

Comment: Maybe not practical enough for your use case, I couldn't say, but also note that you can see what *would* be pushed (without actually sending anything) with the `--dry-run` flag in your push command (in CLI)

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks that makes sense.  But given that's the case, is --dry-run the only way to visibly see what tags will be pushed?  With SVN, it's very simple because I just commit to GitHub then tag to GitHub.  So GitHub is updated instantly which means I can't go wrong.  But with Git, tags need to be manually pushed and until that happens, I can't see them locally so when I push, it feels like I'm pushing blindly.

Comment: @RomainValeri What I mean is, TortoiseGit shows me the files that have changed (with the pretty icons) and after push, the icons all change to green so it's easy to see that the files are synced.  I love that.  But tags seem to be invisible so I might push but forget to check the 'Include tags' checkbox and then the tag won't be pushed and the release won't be on GitHub.  This makes it confusing because I can't see the tags locally.

Comment: I get your concern, but am not a TortoiseGit user myself, I'll let others with a better vision of the tool answer you. This might just be solvable by the tool's UI settings, I couldn't say.